# The send transactions "from" field must be defined using Infura web3

Tags: web3js, accounts, ropsten, infura, web3-providers

when I try to send my transaction using infura I get this error

```
      "The send transactions "from" field must be defined"
```

My problem is my web3 object. When I used Metamask and my app from a  Google Chrome page I did't have problem

```
  App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
```

Now, using Truffle, I need to interact with my smart contract without metamask.

I get my web3 from infura.

```
    App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/2a8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider)
```

(UPDATE) Iteraction with my Smart Contract

```
    const partecipazioneContest = await $.getJSON('File.json')
    App.contracts.PartecipazioneContest = TruffleContract(partecipazioneContest)
    App.contracts.PartecipazioneContest.setProvider(App.web3Provider)
    App.partecipazioneContest = await App.contracts.PartecipazioneContest.deployed()
```

Error when I make the transaction:

```
  await App.partecipazioneContest.addUser(parameters);
```

I think my problem is that it does't load  my account, so I create my account from my private key and i get the correct addres, but when I try to get my account with getAccount() function the accounts are empty.

```
    await web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('0x33434XXXXXXXXXXX13');
    web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(acc){ 
      accounts = acc 
      console.log(accounts)
      alert(" getAccounts " + accounts)

    })
```

How to load my web3 returned from infura with my accounts and all the information that i need to interact with the smart contracts?
I would like to interact with my Smart contract with my wallet on Metamask passing by infura

Comment: You need to unlock your account on Infura, for Truffle to be able to retrieve it from there.

Comment: @goodvibration is It possible? I'm reading : "Infura does not support "unlocking" accounts. Instead, users should send already signed raw transactions using eth_sendRawTransaction."
https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/json-rpc/ratelimits

Comment: No, of course it's not possible, since anyone else connected to that Infura node will be able to use your unlocked account at will.

Comment: @goodvibration so Dd you have any suggestion? I have had un update for interaction with my Smart Contract.

Comment: Of course, exactly as suggested to you in the Infura documentation that you've linked above - sign the transaction with your account's private key, and then send the already-signed transaction instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wrap Web3.js provider with a [Truffle HDWalletProvider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/hdwallet-provider).

HDWalletProvider wraps the underlying provider and allows you easily use `send()` with ETH and smart contract transactions with the existing web3.js and contract APIs.

- Wrap web3 provider with HDWalletProvider
- Import your private keys to HDWalletProvider
- Interact with smart contracts and such, set `send({from: ...})` to an account that maches the imported private keys